# Google Charts Pie Slice Text alignement

Tags: google-visualization

I'm drawing a piechart in Google Charts. My issue is that it has a lot of slices so the text inside isn't shown

Example:
Sample piechart (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ohwM.png)

Is there a way to show the text on the slices coming out from the center of the pie? that way with smaller slides you can still see the text

Thanks!

I tried several codes but to be honest was 100% unable to get even close. Everytime the text is shown horizontally and not coming from the middle of the pie

Sample code showing this (labels in horizontal by default):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pie Chart with Angled Labels</title>
  <!-- Include Google Charts library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7],
    ['Exercise', 4],
    ['Socialize', 2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: 'black',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    legend:'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}



</script>  
  <!-- Create a container for the pie chart -->
  <div id="chartContainer"></div>

  <!-- Include your custom JavaScript code here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done, thank you!